# number format exception: for string "" when using <spring:bind> tag with form checkboxes

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using spring 3.0, in my jsp i have a couple of checkboxes (the normal ones `<input type="checkbox" ....>`). I'm using the `<spring:bind path="businessL1">` to bind it with the bean with property `String[] businessL1;`
the checkboxes look something like this (in html) :-

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="businessL1[]">
```

Now when every i try to submit the form the following exception is thrown:-

```
[org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.error.GenericError_jsp] -  Generic Error:
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at                                      
   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:938)
at 
   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
at........
```

I'm have no conversions being done, everything is of String type.
the controller i'm using is a simple form controller
by the way the rest of the properties i.e the non checkbox type like text etc. are being set in the bean successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't need square brakets to bind checkbox values to `String[]`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="businessL1">
```

Comment: thanks....i didn't realize that could be the problem since these checkboxes were being created by a jquery plugin :)....i edited it and now everything seems to work fine (atleast for now)